# How can I avoid migrations using Entity Framework Code First with Existing Database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two tables each with ten columns in a SQL Server database, so it would be trivial to write -- and, if necessary update -- my own POCO classes by hand, without using the VS wizard. I would like to be able to  avoid migrations for updates, as this is such a simple project, but I can't find any examples via Google or SO.

Has anyone done this? Or does anyone know of an existing example?

I am using Entity Framework 6, VS 2015 Community.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable model checking (and migration)

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<YourContext>(null);
```

**EDIT**

With this statement you disable database initializer so your database must already exists (as in your case). You can choose between different initializers (default for code first is `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`).

You can use this [static] statement before using the context.
In my application (I don't use standard migrations) I insert this statement in static constructor of the context.

```
class YourContext:DbContext
{
    static YourContext()
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<YourContext>(null); 
    }

    //
    // DbSets
    //

    // Model configurations
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I've googled this and what I've found is mostly related to code first development databases and haven't found anything discussing how it works to prevent migrations. Are you able to elaborate on that a bit? Thanks.

Comment: I updated the answer. Hope I understood your needs. You can have a look to several documents. Consider that you can have no migration, automatic migration or code migration (that you can scaffold using packet manager console). If you have automatic migration or code migration you can also specify a configuration (for example to specify if data loss is allowed or not)

Comment: Thank you very much. I can now change the model and the corresponding column in the database with no errors.